# Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Please give me a function $f$ which is a bounded continuous function on $S$ but not integrable over $S$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

In this book, the definition of the **integral** of $f$ over $S$ is the following:

> Definition:
>   Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$;  let $f : S \to  \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Define $f_S : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by the equation
>   $f_S(x) := f(x)$ for $x \in S$ and $f_S(x) := 0$ for $x \notin S$. Choose a rectangle $Q$ containing $S$. We define the **integral** of $f$ over $S$ by the equation
>   $$\int_S f = \int_Q f_S,$$
>   provided the latter integral exists. And this definition is independent of the choice of $Q$.

There is the following theorem in this book:

> Theorem 13.5:
>   Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>   Let $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function.
>   Let $E$ be the set of points $x_0$ of the boundary of $S$ for which the condition $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = 0$ fails to hold.
>   If $E$ has measure zero, then $f$ is integrable over $S$.

---

> Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>   Let $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function.
>   There is $S$ and a function $f$ on $S$ such that $f$ is not integrable over $S$.

I want to know the example of such pair $S$ and $f$.

Comment: I always thought that continuity implies integrability

Comment: There exists no such function as continuity implies integrability.

Comment: Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  
Let $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function.  
Let $E$ be the set of points $x_0$ of the boundary of $S$ for which the condition $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = 0$ fails to hold. If $E$ has measure zero, then $f$ is integrable over $S$.

Comment: There is the above theorem(p.109 Theorem 13.5) in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

Comment: For all those saying continuity implies integrability, that's on a compact region.

Comment: Please include Munkres defines such an integral fir general $S$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for your comment. I edited my question, but I am very poor at English and I was not able to understand what you were saying exactly.

Comment: OK, so now you gave the definition. You will need a set $S$ whose boundary does not have measure $0$, and then take $f=1$ on $S$. The condition in Munkres's theorem is sufficient, but not necessary.

Comment: In the case $n = 1$, you can take a homeomorphism $\phi$ of the open interval $S = (0,1)$ with $\mathbb{R}$ and consider functions $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ that are bounded but not integrable. Then consider $f \circ \phi$ (although this is not in the spirit of the theorem cited.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for your huge hint. I answered my question based on your huge hint.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Thank you very much for your answer. Let $S = (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\phi(x) = \tan(x)$ and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $f$ is not integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. But $f \circ \phi$ is integrable over $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

If the boundary of $S$ has measure zero, then $f$ is integrable over $S$.

So the boundary of $S$ needs to have measure non-zero.

Let $S = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{Q}^2 | 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \}$.

Then, $S$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the boundary of $S$ is equal to $Q : =\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \}$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $f(x, y) := 1$ for all $(x, y) \in S$.

Then, $f$ is a bounded continuous function on $S$.

But $f$ is not integrable over $S$ because the lower integral of $f_S$ over $Q$ is $0$ and the upper integral of $f_S$ over $Q$ is $1$.